# Intuition for Penalizing Larger Coefficients in Regularization

Tags: regression, machine-learning, regularization

In Ridge Regression, what is the intuition for penalizing larger coefficients? Why is a model with smaller coefficients "less complex" and less likely to overfit?

Comment: Maybe do you refer to LASSO regression?? Because, Ridge Regression doesn't reduce the complexity in the sense that you discard nonsignificant variables, but it helps you to mitigate multicollinearity.

Answer (score 1):

Decreasing the coefficients brings you closer to the null model (intercept-only), and so is "simpler" in that sense.

I think a more robust explanation (but still shooting for intuitive) is based on the bias-variance tradeoff.  An OLS model has some variance in the parameter estimates; if you shrink them with regularization, you shrink *all* of the possible parameter estimates (across different samples) towards zero, and hence towards *each other*, and so you reduce the variance.  We simultaneously increase the bias, but fairly often the net effect is beneficial.